# Trace HTTPS Web API calls from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, https, postman, fiddler, web-api-testing

I am working with an iPhone application which interacts with a Web API. Since the **endpoints are HTTPS**, the data which communicates in-between the device and the Web API are suppose to be encrypted.

I am in need of **finding every End-Points and the Data which communicates (Headers, Body Content) for each business scenario** & for negative testing-flows.

Since the data which transmits are encrypted, I was unable to trace from the Fiddler which I tried while referring so several on-line tutorials.

(The reason why I am in need is because of I have got assigned to make a API Automation tool to simulate all the testing scenarios (happy-path, negative test-cases, etc))

Is there any better approach I can take to trace these API calls?
OR, is there a tool which I can try to trace these Web API calls which sends and receives from the iPhone?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the Certificates for the HTTPS endpoints and added to the Certificate Manager (in a windows pc). Afterwards configured the proxy ports with fiddler echo service from the mobile device and was able to trace the HTTPs calls.

With the help of installing the certificates the HTTPS, intercepting the HTTPS is possible.